# How to get an error instead of just warning LNK4006 "... already defined in ... second definition ignored"?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, linker

When building a static library which contains duplicate definition of a function, MSVC++ 2013 gives me just a warning:

```
LNK4006 "... already defined in ... second definition ignored"?
```

I'm afraid that a warning is too easy to miss. Is it possible to make MSVC++ 2013 to report an error and fail the build if multiple definitions for the same function is found (in different .cpp files)?

Note that the reverse of the solution [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1037221/1915854) (i.e. Project Settings > linker > uncheck 'Force file output') is not applicable because that's for an executable, but in this question a static library is in focus thus no "linker" project option.

Comment: You could always treat warnings as errors.

Comment: @Rakete1111, thanks, I thought this option is only available for C/C++ compiler, but not for linker or librarian.

Comment: Actually, I thought this also for linker warnings, but now I'm not sure :/

Comment: @Rakete1111, there are separate "treat warnings as errors" for linker and librarian under Project Properties (as well as for compiler). You can post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a way to treat specific warnings as errors. You can however treat *every* linker warning as error:

Go to: `Project Properties -> Linker -> General -> Treat Linker Warnings As Errors` and switch it to `Yes (/WX)`.